# Parameterizing a Moose subtype by another subtype via coercion

Tags: perl, oop, moose, coercion, moosex-types

I'm unsuccessfully trying to create a type `_Varchar` which would use another type `_VarcharRange` as a parameter. `_VarcharRange`, in turn, can be coerced from one of the Moose base types.

Let me start with `_Varchar_Range` as an example

```
package MyTypes;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moose;
use MooseX::Types::Moose qw(Str Int ArrayRef HashRef);
use MooseX::Types::Common::Numeric qw( PositiveOrZeroInt );
use MooseX::Types::Parameterizable qw(Parameterizable);
use MooseX::Types -declare=>[qw(_VarcharRange)];

subtype _VarcharRange,

    as HashRef[PositiveOrZeroInt], # Must ask for it from MooseX

    where {
        return 0 if ( grep {$_ ne 'min' && $_ ne 'max' } keys %{$_});
        return ( $_->{min} <= $_->{max} ) if ( defined $_->{max} && defined $_->{min} );
        return 1;
    },

    message {"Trololo"};

coerce _VarcharRange,

  from ArrayRef[PositiveOrZeroInt],

  via {
    my $result;
    my @keys = qw(min max);

    foreach my $val (reverse @$_) {
        my $key = pop @keys // 'bad_range';
        $result->{$key} = $val;
    }

    return $result;
  };

has 'my_range' => ( isa => _VarcharRange, is => 'ro', coerce => 1 );

1;
```

And the corresponding test file:

```
!/usr/bin/env perl

use MyTypes qw(_VarcharRange);

my $check = MyTypes->new(
    #my_range => [5, 10],   # works fine
    #my_range => [1, 0],    # fails, as expected
    #my_range => [0, 1, 2], # fails, as expected
    #my_range => [10],      # works fine
);
```

So far so good, but now I try to add a type `_Varchar` parameterizable by `_VarcharRange`. Adding it to `MyTypes.pm`:

```
subtype _Varchar,

    as Parameterizable[Str, _VarcharRange],

    where {
        my ( $string, $range ) = @_;
        my $len = length($string);
        return 0 if ($range->{min} && $len < $range->{min});
        return 0 if ($range->{max} && $len > $range->{max});
        return 1;
    },

    message { "'$_[0]' length is not within range $_[1]->{min} - $_[1]->{max}" };

    has 'my_string' => ( isa => _Varchar[ [1, 10] ], is => 'ro' );
```

And this does not work.

What I expected is that `_VarcharRange` would be implicitly created by coercion from `[1, 10]` array reference. But looks like my code does not even proceed to creating `_VarcharRange`, since I'm trying to parameterize my `_Varchar` directly with `ArrayRef`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Pass an array reference as a parameter, but have intermediate type `_VarcharRange` coerced from it and actually be used for parameterization.

I don't want to parameterize `_Varchar` directly from `ArrayRef` because it is not very object-oriented. It feels like having an independent type for a range is the correct way.

Comment: I tidied your question so that I could read it, and in the process suffered some culture shock! I had never heard of the spelling *parametrize*; in England it is only *parameterise* and your spelling jarred. Given that the types module is called `MooseX::Types::Parameterizable` I copied that spelling throughout. I'm happy to concede your `z` ("zed") instead of our `s`. I hope you're happy with the changes.

Comment: @Borodin that comment made me literally laugh out loud. :)

Comment: @Borodin I had never seen that spelling either, but [apparently it's correct](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79847/parametrise-or-parameterise-a-curve).

Comment: I can't install MooseX::Types::Parameterizable because there's a test failing. Someone opened [a PR in 2015](https://github.com/jjn1056/MooseX-Types-Parameterizable/pull/9) to deprecate it and skip the failing tests. Maybe you should look at Type::Tiny instead.

Comment: Gentlemen, thanks for the comments. I'm now trying to approach the same task via Type::Tiny ,not MooseX::Types::Parametrizable, and [reposted the question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517460/parametrizing-type-with-another-type-using-typetiny)